# Implementing python decorators in a toy example

Tags: python, python-decorators, python-3.8

I have been trying to find a use case to learn decorators and I think I have found one which is relevant to me.

I am using the following codes.

In the file `class1.py` I have:

```
import pandas as pd, os

class myClass():
    def __init__(self):
        fnDone = f'C:\user1\Desktop\loc1\fn.csv'
        if os.path.exists(fnDone): return
        self.Fn1()
        pd.DataFrame({'Done': 1}, index=[0]).to_csv(fnDone)

    def Fn1(self):
        print('something')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myClass()
```

In the file `class2.py` I have:

```
class myClassInAnotherFile():
    def __init__(self):
        fnDone = f'C:\user1\Desktop\loc2\fn.csv'
        if os.path.exists(fnDone): return
        self.Fn1()
        self.Fn2()
        pd.DataFrame({'Done': 1}, index=[0]).to_csv(fnDone)

    def Fn1(self):
        print('something')

    def Fn2(self):
        print('something else')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myClassInAnotherFile('DoneFile12)
```

Is there a way to define a generic decorator code in another file called `utilities.py` so that I can do something of the following sort:

Desired in the file `class1.py` I have:

```
import pandas as pd, os

class myClass():
    def __init__(self):
        fnDone = f'C:\user1\Desktop\loc1\fn.csv'
        self.Fn1()
        pd.DataFrame({'Done': 1}, index=[0]).to_csv(fnDone)

    def Fn1(self):
        print('something')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    @myDecorator
    myClass()
```

In the file `class2.py` I have:

```
class myClassInAnotherFile():
    def __init__(self):
        fnDone = f'C:\user1\Desktop\loc2\fn.csv'
        self.Fn1()
        self.Fn2()
        pd.DataFrame({'Done': 1}, index=[0]).to_csv(fnDone)

    def Fn1(self):
        print('something')

    def Fn2(self):
        print('something else')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    @myDecorator
    myClassInAnotherFile()
```

Essentially mimicking the original behavior using a decorator.

Edit1:
I am looking to extend the functionality of my class definitions. In the both original class definitions, I repeat the code which checks for `fnDone` file and if it is present, exits the class. **Goal is to have a decorator which checks for the `fnDone` file and exits the class if it is present.**

Edit2:
I can do this as a function also but I am trying to learn how to extend functionality of a class or method using decorators.

Edit3:
Does it make it easier if I have the following instead in `class1.py`:

```
def myClass():
    fnDone = f'C:\user1\Desktop\loc1\fn.csv'
    if os.path.exists(fnDone): return
    self.Fn1()
    pd.DataFrame({'Done': 1}, index=[0]).to_csv(fnDone)

def Fn1(self):
    print('something')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myClass()
```

and `class2.py` as following:

```
def myClassInAnotherFile():
    fnDone = f'C:\user1\Desktop\loc2\fn.csv'
    if os.path.exists(fnDone): return
    self.Fn1()
    self.Fn2()
    pd.DataFrame({'Done': 1}, index=[0]).to_csv(fnDone)

def Fn1(self):
    print('something')

def Fn2(self):
    print('something else')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myClassInAnotherFile('DoneFile12)
```

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear what the decorator is supposed to do here. The only difference seems to be that the (somewhat fishy) use of ``fnDone`` is removed from ``__init__`` – something a decorator cannot do.

Comment: I'm still not sure exactly what you are trying to accomplish, but decorators might not be the right tool.  Setting aside decorators (or any other implementation details) what is it you want to be able to do?

Comment: Also, in general, using the `__init__` method of a class to group together some tasks doesn't generally make a lot of sense.  Why not just write a function?

Comment: It is reasonably straightforward to have a decorator check some external indicator and/or cache some result *if the indicator is known to the decorator*. However, *extracting* the indicator from a local variable inside a function is somewhere between "tricky and brittle" to "impossible", depending on how much metaprogramming and loss of portability one accepts. It's certainly not something one should lightheartedly add on top of a design that is questionable to begin with.

Comment: So, *iff* ``fnDone`` is a literal and *iff* nothing must run before it, ``myDecorator`` can inspect the bytecode of its arguments ``__init__`` to get ``fnDone`` – that's ``cls.__init__.__code__.co_consts[1]`` (assuming the class is passed as ``cls``) – then check whether ``fnDone`` exists and otherwise run the function then write ``fnDone``.

Comment: perhaps, this isn't the best toy task to learn decorators. In this problem, inheritance would make a much cleaner solution and decorators are sort of an antipattern

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `fnDone` is a local variable rather than a parameter, it makes using a decorator a bit awkward. If you modify the code slightly to pass in `fnDone` as a parameter, it makes using a decorator more of a viable option.

For example, you could make a decorator that wraps the constructor of an object, and checks if the file passed in exist or not:

```
import os.path
from functools import wraps

import pandas as pd

def check_file_exists(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def _inner(self, fn_done):
        if os.path.exists(fn_done):
            return
        f(self, fn_done)
    return _inner

class MyClass:
    @check_file_exists
    def __init__(self, fn_done) -> None:
        pd.DataFrame({'Done': 1}, index=[0]).to_csv(fn_done)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyClass("fn.csv")
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a decorator checking if the file exists before running your code:

File: `my_decorator.py`

```
import os
import pandas as pd


def checkDoneDecorator(doneFilename):
    def _decorator(decorated):
        def _wrapper_function(*args, **kwargs):
            if os.path.exists(doneFilename):
                return

            try:
                result = decorated(*args, **kwargs)
            finally:
                pd.DataFrame({'Done': 1}, index=[0]).to_csv(doneFilename)
        return _wrapper_function
    return _decorator
```

File: `class1.py`

```
from my_decorator import checkDoneDecorator


@checkDoneDecorator(doneFilename='C:\user1\Desktop\loc1\fn.csv')
def myClass():
    Fn1()


def Fn1():
    print('something')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    myClass()
```

File: `class2.py`

```
from my_decorator import checkDoneDecorator


@checkDoneDecorator(doneFilename='C:\user1\Desktop\loc2\fn.csv')
def myClassInAnotherFile():
    Fn1()
    Fn2()


def Fn1():
    print('something')


def Fn2():
    print('something else')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    myClassInAnotherFile()
```

Some notes:

- I used a decorator with argument `doneFilename`, which adds one more level of nested function than a simple decorator. You can see a detailed example [here](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=240845#decorator-functions-with-decorator-arguments).
- I also included the writing of the `doneFilename` inside the decorator, since the file check and the file writing are related. This is not mandatory though.
- I removed the `self` arguments from your examples, as a class is not really needed in this example. If you really need a class, please don't put the decorator on `__init__` and do it like this:

```
class myClass:

    @checkDoneDecorator(doneFilename='C:\user1\Desktop\loc1\fn.csv')
    def start(self):
        self.Fn1()

    def Fn1(self):
        print('something')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myClass().start()
```

Answer (score 2):

I upvoted the answer given by @pigeonhands since you were primarily interested in in using a class. But this is how I would accomplish your goal using regular functions, which I think makes more sense. For the same reason offered by @pigeonhands, it makes sense to have the CSV filename be an argument to the `myclass` function as argument name *fnDone*:

```py
import os.path
from functools import wraps

import pandas as pd

def myDecorator(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(fnDone):
        if os.path.exists(fnDone):
            return
        func(fnDone)
    return wrapper

@myDecorator
def myClass(fnDone):
    Fn1()
    pd.DataFrame({'Done': 1}, index=[0]).to_csv(fnDone)

def Fn1():
    print('something')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myClass('test1.csv')
```